# How do I change from a Github account to a BitBucket account when pushing a commit on IntelliJ?

Tags: github, intellij-idea, bitbucket, account

I have a work repository where I have to use a BitBucket account for pushing commits. However, when I do so, it pushes using my personal Github account. This happens on my desktop PC but recently it started to happen on my laptop as well, even though it used to push using the BitBucket account.

How do I remove my Github account from Intellij? Is there anyway for me to only have my BitBucket account associated with IntelliJ while having other programs use the Github account instead?

- tried ticking on and off the "Use Credentials Helper" box in IntelliJ settings, still asks me for my Github credentials
- reinstalled IntelliJ which did not solve it

Comment: I would configure this using `git` on the command line personally, and let IntelliJ pick up the changes. A google search for setting the user/email of the repository will let you change it on a per-project basis, and you can also update your global settings.

Comment: There is no BitBucket integration for now, so IDE works with BitBucket as with any other regular git server.

When you are pushing - please try to choose right remote repository in Push dialog (press on an remote repository name to change location)